# need help to create autocomplete textbox in joomla 3.5.1 (while fetching data from database)

Tags: php, database, jquery-ui, joomla

**html code**

`<input type="text" id="mytextid">`

**Jquery**

```
jQuery(function() {
        jQuery( "#mytextid" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "modules/mod_djc2search/tmpl/auto.php",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {
                        q: request.term
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( data );
                    }
                });
            },
        });
    });
```

**php**

`

```
<?php
$search = $_REQUEST["q"];
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT * FROM ts_djc2_categories WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->query();
$json = array();
$tt = "Nothing Found."
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
array_push($json, $row['name']);
}
else {
array_push($json, $tt);
}
echo json_encode($json);
}
?>
```

`

I also added jqueryUI.js file and the CSS file also. But its not working.
Also please let me know where to place the php file. 
Please help me out of this. thanks.

Comment: please attach error which you getting.

Comment: nothing is displaying..

Comment: it will comes in console. as you are running ajax.

Comment: TypeError: jQuery(...).autocomplete is not a function

Comment: you seems forget to add autocomplete.js

Comment: after adding it showing : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in E:\files\htdocs\themestock\modules\mod_djc2search\tmpl\auto.php on line 24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change your PHP file code and correct it here. Please check it seems one bracket extra.
Also dont forget to add autocomplete.js file.

**PHP file**

```
<?php
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../' ));  
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );

$db = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$search = $_REQUEST["q"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM ts_djc2_categories WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->query();
$json = array();
$tt = "Nothing Found.";
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($json, $row['name']);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        array_push($json, $tt);
    }

    echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, But still its showing error:  <b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'JFactory' not found in <b>E:\files\htdocs\themestock\modules\mod_djc2search
\tmpl\auto.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />

Comment: Please give your positive feedback if its useful to you. @user2980415